# Getting Implicit Converstion Error

Tags: ruby, text, implicit-conversion

I have created an item class and am trying to rake test it. When running the code outside the test no errors are thrown. Because of this i assume i am testing it wrong.

```
    class Item
        attr_accessor :name, :description, :item
           def initialize (item, description, name)
                @name = item[:name]
                @description = item[description]
           end
    end
```

And the code i am using to test it is

```
    require "Asheron's_call/Item.rb"
    require "Test/Unit"

      class TestGame < Test::Unit::TestCase

      def test_item
      one = Item.new ("Potion","Red")
      assert_equal("Potion", one.name)
    end
  end


   =>93: one = Item.new ("Potion","Red")
     94:  assert_equal("Potion", one.name
```

when running the test with that i am getting a new error which is a syntax error. It is expecting a ')' after potion. When i changed that to see what would happen and then came back saying it expected me to place 'end' which to me feels wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The test is fine. The `Item`’s constructor is not:

```
class Item
    attr_accessor :name, :description
    def initialize (name, description)
      @name = name
      @description = description
    end
end
```

There is no `item` there. Also, in the test one should assert the instance, not the class:

```
# wrong: assert_equal("Potion", Item.name)
assert_equal("Potion", one.name)
```

Comment: tried that as well and still the same error as above.